# How to generate multivariate random numbers with different marginal distributions?

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, distribution

I have lost idea how to generate some bivariate random mumbers, say in copula. The marginals are of different distribution, i.e. t, gamma, and the joint structure can be gaussian or t. I will have to fixed their kendall tau. And I want to examine how the pearson rho of those random numbers are different from the presetted tau.

Any suggestion? A piece of prototype in R/Matlab is highly appreciated!

Comment: For copulas in R, you could take a look at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Statistics Toolbox you can generate random numbers from copulas using the function `copularnd`. There are several examples in the documentation. To convert between using Kendall's tau and Pearson's rho, take a look at `copulaparam` and `copulastat`.

Comment: Thank you @Sam Roberts. For someone else has the similar question like this, try:

>> tau = 0.5;    % Predefine the Kendall's tau 

>> rho = copulaparam('gaussian',tau);    % Convert tau to Pearson's rho 

>> uu = copularnd('gaussian',rho,5000);  % generate random numbers in Gaussian copula

>> aa = tinv(uu(:,1),5);    % transform uniforms to t margin (df=5)

>> bb = norminv(uu(:,2));   % transform uniforms to standard normal margin 

>> scatter(aa,bb);     % scatter plot

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a Gaussian copula as follows. Of course, the copulas are not guaranteed to exactly hit your desired target correlation. That performance depends on the properties of the marginal distributions.

**Example 1:** Using Inverse Transform for Marginals (Exponential & Weibull)

```
rng(1776)   % Setting seed for reproducibility
lambda1 = 2; alpha1 = 2; beta = 3;
rho = 0.8; N = 10^5;

Z = mvnrnd([0 0],[1 rho; rho 1], N);
U = normcdf(Z);
X1 = (-1/lambda1)*log(U(:,1));  % Inverse Transform for Exponential
Y1 = beta*(-log(U(:,2))).^(1/alpha1);  % Inverse Transform for Weibull
corr(X1,Y1)
scatterhist(X1,Y1,'Direction','out','Marker','.','Color','b')
```

[image: Gaussian Copula w/ Inverse Transform]

**Example 2:** Using Numerical CDF Inversion for Marginals (Gamma & Lognormal)

```
rng(1776)
alpha2 = 6.7; lambda2 = 3; 
mu = 0.1; sigma = 0.5;
rho = -0.8; N = 10^5;
% Make distributions
pd_X2 = makedist('Gamma',alpha2,lambda2);
pd_Y2 = makedist('Lognormal',mu,sigma);
Z = mvnrnd([0 0],[1 rho; rho 1], N);
U = normcdf(Z);
X2 = icdf(pd_X2,U(:,1));
Y2 = icdf(pd_Y2,U(:,2));
corr(X2,Y2)
scatterhist(X2,Y2,'Direction','out','Marker','.','Color','k')
```

[image: Gaussian Copula w/ Numerical CDF Inversion]

**References:**
[Inverse Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)
[Copulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory))

Gaussian copula:
Ross, Sheldon. (2013). *Simulation*. Academic Press, San Diego, CA, 5th edition. 103–105.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, no worries. I wasn't sure how to handle that situation (already deleted that answer).  I didn't know if a duplicate flag was appropriate or not based on timelines and other details.  Now I know!   Btw, does a duplicate flag lead to merging if appropriate?

Comment: A duplicate flag gets the question put on the close review queue. There people can vote to close as duplicate. Once you have enough rep you’ll be able to directly vote to close, instead of flagging. You can also come to the MATLAB chat to ask with help closing questions. Questions closed as duplicate stay around, we like those because they serve as sign posts. Even if the question is not closed, the flagging leaves a comment pointing at the other question, which will help people find it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two different variables x1, x2 you can use the copula theory in order to generate some random numbers. So you have to compute the CDF of the variables:

```
[Fi1, xi1] = ecdf(x1);

[Fi2, xi2] = ecdf(x2);
```

or

```
Fi1 = ksdensity(x1,x1, 'function','cdf');

Fi2 = ksdensity(x2,x2, 'function','cdf');
```

Subsequently, you can compute the kendall's tau correlation as follows:

```
tau = corr(x1,x2, 'type', 'kendall');

rho = copulaparam('t',tau, nu, 'type','kendall');
```

With the aim of copularnd you can generate random values (n=1000) of Gaussian, t,  Clayton, Frank, or Gumbel copula and then you only have to estimate the inverse cdf of the copula with the aim of the desired distribution.

```
n = 1000;

U = copularnd('Gaussian',[1  rho;rho 1],n);

% Inverse cdf of Gamma distribution 

X1 = gaminv(U(:,1),2,1);

% Inverse cdf of Student's t distribution

X2 = tinv(U(:,2),5);
```

or

```
X1 = ksdensity(x1, U(:,1), 'function','icdf','width',.15);
X2 = ksdensity(x2, U(:,2), 'function','icdf','width',.15);
```

So, now the X1 and X2 represent the new random values that have been generated from the initial x1 and x2 variables.

I am new in copula statistics, so excuse me if I made a mistake..