# Generating two correlated random vectors

Tags: matlab, correlation

I want to generate two random vectors with a specified correlation. Each element of the second vector must be correlated with the corresponding element of the first vector and independent of others.

How could I do this in MATLAB?

By the way the elements of  the first vector dont have the same distribution, I mean each element of the first vector should have different variances. (the vector is made of 7 variable with different variances.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 correlated vectors in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511082/2-correlated-vectors-in-matlab)

Comment: By the way the elements of the first vector dont have the same distribution, I mean each element of the first vector should have different variances. (the vector is made of 7 variable with different variances. How about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate multivariate random numbers with different marginal distributions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582583/how-to-generate-multivariate-random-numbers-with-different-marginal-distribution)

Answer (score 3):

As described in [this Mathworks article](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-CYHA89/index.html), you can do the following:

1. Generate two random vectors (*i.e* a random matrix with two columns). Let's say that you want the distribution of each element in the matrix to be Gaussian with zero mean and unit variance:

   ```
   N = 1000;             %// Number of samples in each vector
   M = randn(N, 2);
   ```

   You can obviously use any distribution to your liking.
2. Now the trick: multiply the matrix with an upper triangular matrix obtained by the Cholesky decomposition of the desired correlation matrix `R`:

   ```
   R = [1 0.75; 0.75 1]; %// Our correlation matrix, taken from the article
   M = M * chol(R);
   ```
3. Extract your random vectors from the modified matrix `M`:

   ```
   x = M(:, 1);
   y = M(:, 2);
   ```

Comment: can you generalize this example to a non-predefined number of columns?

Comment: @Zizou23 The original question is about two correlated vectors, so what you are asking is different. Having said that, I am pretty sure that it can be worked out.

Answer (score 0):

The cholasky decomposition might fail if there are variable with same correlation. so use SVD. I do it like
this. mu is vector having mean of targeted random variables with normal distribution. Sigma is the the required co-variance matrix. n is length of required random variables and d is number of random variables

```
mu=mu(:)';
[U S V]=svd(Sigma);
S=round(S*1e6)/1e6;
S=sqrt(S);   
s=randn(n, d) * S * U'+mu(ones(n,1),:);
```