# How can I generate correlated data in MATLAB, with a prespecified SD and mean?

Tags: matlab

I wish to create one vector of data points with a mean of 50 and a standard deviation of 1. Then, I wish to create a second vector of data points again with a mean of 50 and a standard deviation of 1, and with a correlation of 0.3 with the first vector. The number of data points doesn't really matter but ideally I would have 100.

The method mentioned at [Generating two correlated random vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713469/generating-two-correlated-random-vectors) does not answer my question because (due to random sampling) the SDs and means deviate too much from the desired number.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a way, though it is ugly. I would still welcome an answer that detailed a more elegant method to get what I want.

```
z = 0;

while z < 1
    mu = 50
    sigma = 1
    M = mu + sigma*randn(100,2);
    R = [1 0.3; 0.3 1];
    L = chol(R)
    M = M*L;
    x = M(:,1);
    y = M(:,2);
    if (corr(x,y) < 0.301 & corr(x,y) > 0.299) & (std(x) < 1.01 & std(x) > 0.99) & (std(y) < 1.01 & std(y) > 0.99);
    z = 1;
    end
end
```

I then calculated how the mean of vector y and calculated how much higher than 50 it was. I then subtracted that number from every element in vector y so that the mean was reduced to 50.

Answer (score 0):

You can create both vectors together... I dont understand the reason you define them separatelly. This is the concept of multivariate distribution (just to be sure that we have the same jargon)...
Anyway, I guess you are almost already there to what I call the simplest way to do that:

Method 1:

Use matlab function [mvnrnd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html) [Remember that mvnrnd uses the covariance matrix that can be calculated from the correlation and the variance)

Method 2:

I am not very sure, but I think it is very close to what you are doing (actually my doubt is related to the `if (corr(x,y) < 0.301 & corr(x,y) > 0.299) & (std(x) < 1.01 & std(x) > 0.99) & (std(y) < 1.01 & std(y) > 0.99)`) I dont understand the reason you have to do that. See the topic "Drawing values from the distribution" in wikipedia [Multivariate normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution).