# Generating two correlated uniform random variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, correlation, uniform-distribution

Like the title suggests, I am facing difficulty in understanding how we generate two correlated uniform [0,1] random variables. I am new to the idea of copulas.

I am struggling to write a MATLAB code wherein I am required to generate two correlated uniform [0,1] random variables.

Comment: Could you add the code that you have tried. People could then comment/correct/modify/improve/critic it. Otherwise it seems like you are asking someone to write the code for you. Also please add the output that you got and the output that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

**Generating correlated uniform random variables with Gaussian Copula**

```
rho = .75; % Desired target correlation
N = 1000;  % Number of samples
Z = mvnrnd([0 0],[1 rho; rho 1], N);
U = normcdf(Z);  % Correlated U(0,1) random variables

scatterhist(U(:,1),U(:,2),'Direction','out') % Visualize (change `rho` to see impact)
```

*Note:* This method is not guaranteed to hit the target correlation exactly but should be close enough for many applications.

[image: 3 Scatter plots with marginal histograms. First plot has target correlation of 0.25; second plot has target correlation of 0.75, third plot has target correlation of -0.95.]

This can be very useful to quickly generate correlated distributions using the [inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) method (either analytically or numerically). Both use cases illustrated below.

**Analytical approach**

```
lambda = 2; alpha = 2; beta = 3;
rho = -.35; N = 1000;
Z = mvnrnd([0 0],[1 rho; rho 1], N);
U = normcdf(Z);
X = (-1/lambda)*log(U(:,1)); % Inverse Transform for Exponential
Y = beta*(-log(U(:,2))).^(1/alpha); % Inverse Transform for Weibull
corr(X,Y)
scatterhist(X,Y,'Direction','out')
```

**Numerical approach**

```
% Parameters
alpha = 6.7; lambda = 3;
mu = 0.1; sigma = 0.5;
rho = 0.75; N = 1000;
% Make distributions
pd_X = makedist('Gamma',alpha,lambda);
pd_Y = makedist('Lognormal',mu,sigma);
Z = mvnrnd([0 0],[1 rho; rho 1], N);
U = normcdf(Z);
% Use Inverse Transform for marginal distributions (numerically)
X = icdf(pd_X,U(:,1)); % Inverse CDF for X
Y = icdf(pd_Y,U(:,2)); % Inverse CDF for Y
corr(X,Y)
scatterhist(X,Y,'Direction','out')
```

**References:**
[Inverse Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)
[Copulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory))

Gaussian copula:
Ross, Sheldon. (2013). *Simulation*. Academic Press, San Diego, CA, 5th edition. 103–105.

Modified related answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52864871/8239061).