# Generate multivariate nonnormal random numbers in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, simulation

## Background

**I want to generate multivariate distributed random numbers with a fixed variance matrix.** For example, I want to generate a 2 dimensional data with `covariance value = 0.5, each dimensional variance = 1`. The first maginal of data is a norm distribution with `mean = 0, sd = 1`, and the next is a exponential distribution with `rate = 2`.

## My attempt

My attempt is that we can generate a correlated multinormal distribution random numbers and then revised them to be any distribution by [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

In below, I give an example about transforming 2 dimensional normal distribution random numbers into a `norm(0,1)+ exp(2)` random number:

```
# generate a correlated multi-normal distribution, data[,1] and data[,2] are standard norm
data <- mvrnorm(n = 1000,mu = c(0,0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),2,2))
# calculate the cdf of dimension 2
exp_cdf = ecdf(data[,2])
Fn = exp_cdf(data[,2])  
# inverse transform sampling to get Exponetial distribution with rate = 2
x = -log(1-Fn + 10^(-5))/2
mean(x);cor(data[,1],x)
```

Out:

```
[1] 0.5035326
[1] 0.436236
```

From the outputs, the new `x` is a set of exponential(rate = 2) random numbers. Also, `x` and `data[,1]` are correlated with `0.43`. The correlated variance is `0.43`, not very close to my original setting value `0.5`. It maybe a issue. I think covariance of sample generated should stay more closer to initial setting value. In general, I think my method is not quite decent, maybe you guys have some amazing code snippets.

### My question

As a statistics graduate, I know there exist 10+ methods to generate multivariate random numbers theoretically. In this post,  I want to collect bunch of code snippets to do it automatically using packages or handy . And then, I will compare them from different aspects, like `time consuming` and `quality of data` etc. Any ideas is appreciated!

### Note

Some users think I am asking for package recommendation. However, I am not looking for any recommendation. I already knew commonly used statistical theroms and R packages. I just wanna know how to **generate multivariate distributed random numbers with a fixed variance matrix decently**  and give a code example about generate `norm + exp` random numbers. I think there must exist more powerful code snippets to do it in a decent way! So I ask for help right now!

*Sources*:

1. [generating-correlated-random-variables, math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2320067/generating-correlated-random-variables-of-different-distributions-via-gaussian-c)
2. [use copulas to generate multivariate random numbers, stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582583/how-to-generate-multivariate-random-numbers-with-different-marginal-distribution)
3. [Ross simulation, theoretical book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/simulation/ross/978-0-12-415825-2)
4. [R CRAN distribution task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html)

Comment: If you've found good ways to answer your question, post them as an answer rather than making a question of it.

Comment: Sure. In this post, I am looking for good ways, so I ask a question.

Comment: Asking for package recommendations is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @42- I want to solve my problem (__generate data with fixed variance matrix__) using codes. There is __nothing__ to do with __Package Recommendations__, why you think I am asking for a package recommendation?

Comment: The inverse transform approach is non-linear and correlation is only preserved under linear transformations. You'll be altering the correlation structure both in going from normals to uniforms, and from uniforms to anything else. I doubt there's a general form solution.